# How download DB MySQL on hosting?

Tags: mysql

This first that I try to download DB MySQL on "godaddy", but I receive this message:

```
Error
There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are correct and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be that you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text area. You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser fails where the command line interface succeeds, please reduce your SQL query input to the single query that causes problems, and submit a bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:

----BEGIN CUT----
eNrt2c1OwkAUBeBDAQODiSyI67tgYwKlLYLQlRXLXwrUFnFpTERDJIUYMfI6PoHv4HtRp01Al26M
Jt4vM5mb07kzyWxre97IM6mlU8sgxx6apJFOjbrWFP5YftgI4U9kWuzdFsVg7V84JtVUTW3Wy/PF
vbj0PRr5JbI69nBcooktW65mAflW2/J68c5a9US4A8skQ9X1aFSF23WjraWRHx2mq3VyZsHqRTjW
sGPSNCivnu7KDRFftkmI/SSQTwCaXNDFjpJBFkhHZWab5eV8ewfENqhUAAJjjDHGGGOMMcb+OgXh
D5y6h14QLM7P+H0ZY4wxxhhjjLHf9pqI/+n/Wwko6KMtqy4Od6m7q/tIKkrhiL4JKWSXj4vl9cN0
jTRycf18M19NkcoahrwOOJXzIAOkc4UCjr8E4bYz/GwL8QHyNkoe
----END CUT----
----BEGIN RAW----
ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 0 1 8609
STR: �

SVN: $Id$
MySQL: 5.0.96-log
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Win SAFARI 5.0.537
PMA: 2.11.11.3
PHP VER,OS: 5.1.6 Linux
LANG: en-utf-8
SQL: �
0H  ��
// �InnoDB�JFHPJ)                                           prop_keyprop_value  22@4@�prop_key�prop_value�
----END RAW----

SQL query:

� 0H    �� // �InnoDB�JFHPJ)    prop_keyprop_value  22@4@�prop_key�prop_value�

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'þ
' at line 1
```

What did wrong I do? I thing this is because version of MySQL, I changed from 5.6 to 5.0.96 and created new table, but receive same result.

Comment: what is the query you are running?

Comment: Did you read the error message you posted, and try the suggestions in that message? If not, go do that. If yes, tell us what happened.

Comment: I try to import file (table) from my computer to hosting goddady. First of all, I thought this is problem because a number a version, I changed it, now I think - it because SQL syntax error, but how can I check it?

Comment: Seems an encoding problem

Comment: try running the SQL on your computer to debug it.  If it works on your local machine it should work on the hosted one.

Comment: `I changed from 5.6 to 5.0.96` => Why did you do that?